# Wikipedia says that a function is uniformly continuous if and only if it admits a modulus of continuity.

Tags: continuity, uniform-continuity

The title statement is from wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulus_of_continuity

But [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/398023/uniformly-continuous-function-modulus-of-continuity) asks about a uniformly continuous function for which there does not exist a modulus of continuity. Can someone explain the apparent contradiction? I don't understand the answer for that question.

Comment: Looks to me that the Wikipedia article is allowing the modulus of continuity to take the value $\infty$, whereas the linked question is explicitly asking about a modulus of continuity which is always real. The counterexample in the answer there (discrete infinite metric space to integers with ordinary metric) allows for a modulus of continuity, but it *has* to be infinite, i.e. $\omega(t)=\infty$ at least for $t\ge 1$.

Comment: yes, that makes sense.